# When is AUTOSAR typically used in a LIN slave?

Tags: autosar

In a typical car, what are the simplest `LIN` slaves which use `AUTOSAR` and what are the most complex `LIN` slaves which do not have `AUTOSAR`?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

AUTOSAR does not yet support an AUTOSAR stack running on a LIN slave. This may change in the future.

Comment: This is supported since AutoSAR 4.4.0. See https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/classic/19-11/AUTOSAR_SRS_LIN.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Discussed use cases are e.g. battery management systems for 12V. Newer ones use CAN here, but older ones used LIN. When you have to retrofit newer packs into older vehicle platforms, you would have to use the existing LIN interface, so no bigger changes in other electronic control units or even the wiring harness are required.